# Image view like google map in android studios

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, imageview

so I wanna make a image view in android studios which can pan, zoom in, zoom out like google maps. in the image view, i only wanna display one picture but i am not able to figure out a way to accomplish that.
pl be as detailed al possible
appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Check this library out - https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer
you can zoom also with double tap

Comment: Hi so i don't think that will work as i want a image view which on rotation using touch should stay rotated